# jQuery center a div shrinking window in an iPad

Tags: jquery, mobile

I'm using the following (jQuery) javascript to center a div:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#window').css({
            position:'absolute',
                left: ($(window).width() - $('#window').outerWidth())/2,
                top: ($(window).height() - $('#window').outerHeight())/2
            });
 });
```

This behaves normally in desktop browsers (i.e. firefox, chrome) however, on an iPad, the screen is resizing before this "window" appears and everything appears shifted to the top left of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my first answer was not useful ! This is the right solution. In my fiddle the size is generated everytime the window is resized. So you can be sure to be centered at every time.

I made a jsfiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/U6fR4/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $(window).resize(function(){

      $('.className').css({
       position:'absolute',
       left: ($(window).width() 
         - $('.className').outerWidth())/2,
       top: ($(window).height() 
         - $('.className').outerHeight())/2
      });

     });

     // To initially run the function:
     $(window).resize();

    });
```